# React Native Navigator set title dynamically iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

```
var MainPage = React.createClass({
   onPress() {
    this.props.navigator.push({
        title: 'Home Page',
        component: Homepage
    });
},

render() {
    return (
        <View style={[styles.scene, {backgroundColor: '#DAF6FF'}]}>
            <TouchableHighlight
              style={styles.menubutton}
              onPress={this.onPress}>
                <Text style={styles.white}>This page</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
            <TouchableHighlight
              style={styles.menubutton}
              onPress={this.onPress}>
                <Text style={styles.white}>That page</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
            <TouchableHighlight
              style={styles.menubutton}
              onPress={this.onPress}>
                <Text style={styles.white}>Another page</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
    );
  }
});
```

How can I send a variable with this.onPress to set the navigator title dynamically? ie if I press 'This page' it would set the title to 'This page' in the onPress function. Also it would be useful to set the component dynamically.

Other than creating separate functions for every menu item there doesn't seem to be any obvious way to achieve this. I've tried various things and searched to no avail.

Comment: are you using navigator or navigatorIOS ?

Comment: I'm using navigatorIOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the title as a paramater to the function:

```
<TouchableHighlight
 style={styles.menubutton}
 onPress={ () => this.onPress('Another page') }>
     <Text style={styles.white}>Another page</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Then, assign it in the navigator function:

```
onPress(title) {
  this.props.navigator.push({
    title: title,
    component: Homepage
  });
}
```

If you wanted to dynamically set the component, you could take it one step further and use a switch statement:

```
onPress(title) {
  switch(title) {
    case 'Another page':
      var component = AnotherPage;
      break;
  }

  this.props.navigator.push({
    title: title,
    component: component
  });
}
```

Comment: Works great. That's weird because I was pretty sure I tried this exactly but somehow it came up with errors. This way certainly works though. For the component there's an even easier method, you can just send it through along with the title ie onPress={ () => this.onPress('Another page',anotherComponent) }>